# Can you adopt a 'specific' single property from another style?

Tags: less

I'm pretty new to LESS and have been playing with ways to reuse properties from existing styles.

Is there a way I get reuse a Single Style/Property (by name) of a known CSS Class, for example:

**This Obviously merges all of .source into .target:**

```
.source { width: 100%; display: block; color: #ff0000; }

.target {
  height: 10px;
  .source;
}
```

**What if I wanted just the width property, something like this:**

```
.source { width: 100%; display: block; color: #ff0000; }

.target {
  height: 10px;
  width : .source:width;
}
```

I've been looking for a while now, and I'm doubtful its possible, but hoping someone has some suggestions.

Essentially I'm hoping to not generate tons of repeated CSS for properties I don't need.

Comment: why not .source, .target { same properties } and exclusive ones in another block?

Comment: the .source is already set in a library and therefore it would be nice to extend it or at least only certain properties of it. Thanks for message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer, Not at Present (as of version 1.7)

There is no way to target just a single property for retrieval without setting up the class to allow access to it. For example, if it was worth it to you, a class could be set up like so:

```
.source { 
    .get(@prop) when (@prop = width), (@prop = all) {width: 100%;} 
    .get(@prop) when (@prop = display), (@prop = all) {display: block;}
    .get(@prop) when (@prop = color), (@prop = all) {color: #ff0000;}
    .get(all);
}

.target {
  height: 10px;
  .source > .get(width);
}
```

This will get the output you want. But as you can see, it involves *much more coding* than just setting the properties on the two items themselves (or setting a global variable for both to access, which would be the better way to go). I cannot think of a situation when it would be best to use the above method, but maybe someone might find this useful.

Comment: Thanks for the info and suggestion. Unfortunately the css classes I'm trying to fetch from are not my own, they come from a library and therefore I have no control over setting them at you describe, but thats for the innovative suggestion.